# Blacklisted by Sorbs only when my MUA in a specific network

Tags: email-server, blacklist

I have: 2 networks A and B; 2 mail boxes abc@domain1.com and abc@domain2.com; destination xyz@gmail.com; a computer with MUA thunderbird.
I'm in network A, send a mail from abc@domain1.com to xyz@gmail.com -> OK
I'm in network A, send a mail from abc@domain2.com to xyz@gmail.com -> OK
I'm in network B, send a mail from abc@domain1.com to xyz@gmail.com -> OK
I'm in network B, send a mail from abc@domain2.com to xyz@gmail.com -> fault :
"5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [82.233.80.57] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net;"
 
As I understand about Sorbs service that my server mail of domain2.com has already been on the blacklisted of Sorbs. But then why in the network A, I can send the mail as nothing happens?